# setlocale on cloudways server

Tags: php, laravel, localization, cloudways

I deploy my laravel project on Cloudways server. Everything is ok, except date localisation. I use

```
setLocale(LC_TIME, 'sk_SK')
```

in my aplication but it doesn't work. After contacting Live chat on Cloudways their response was: "I would like to update you that on our platform on the server level we cannot make any changes because we have our customized server stack".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you installed your locale sk_SK on the server ? Are you able to do that ?
If you can check this link :[Carbon API Localization](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-localization)

Here is what you should type :

```
sudo locale-gen sk_SK.UTF-8
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Comment: Thanks for quick replay! After locale -a I get en.US.utf8 and sk_SK.utf8, so I  have to use setLocale(LC_TIME, 'sk_SK.utf8'). And now it works!